# Intuitive proof for the second directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intuition

I understand that the second directional derivative can be found by taking the gradient vector of the first directional derivative and multiplying it by the given unit vector, as follows:

$$\nabla^2_{\hat{u}} f(x,y,z) := \left\langle\frac{\partial\nabla_{\hat{u}}f(x,y,z)}{\partial x},\frac{\partial\nabla_{\hat{u}}f(x,y,z)}{\partial y},\frac{\partial\nabla_{\hat{u}}f(x,y,z)}{\partial z}\right\rangle\cdot \hat{u}$$

My question is why the second directional derivative isn't instead defined by the following formula:

$$\nabla^2_{\hat{u}} f(x,y,z) \stackrel{?}{=} \underbrace{\left\langle \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial y^2}, \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2}\right\rangle}_{\textrm{The second derivative of the gradient vector}}\cdot \underbrace{\hat{u}}_{\textrm{Unit vector}}$$

Basically why isn't the second directional derivative just the dot product of the second derivative of the gradient vector and the unit vector?

Comment: Your photo is unreadable because it is too small. Did you check it before posting? And what does "the second derivative of the gradient vector" mean?

Comment: I'm afraid the image you've uploaded is in too small resolution to be legible. I can vaguely make out $\left\langle \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial y^2}, \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2}\right\rangle$ but nothing else. May I recommend that you either: 1) Try using mathjax! You can right click on the equation I just wrote and view the code (as TeX commands) if you want to copy it. 2) Upload a higher-quality image, or 3) Write it out poorly without mathjax and cop some downvotes and one of us can mathjax it for you

Comment: I've submitted an edit request mathjaxing what I *think* you meant. When it gets accepted, let me know if I misinterpreted anything.

Comment: If you want the second directional derivative of a scalar function $f$ in the direction of $\mathbf{u}$, you ought to take the derivative of $f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{u})$ with respect to $t$ twice and then evaluate at $t=0$. What you get matches taking the directional derivative twice. There is no good reason to expect it to be the dot product of $\mathbf{u}$ with the second partials other than guessing a formula happens to involve second derivatives and blindly (and incorrectly) generalizing the first directional derivative.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit. The first one is a bit off, but that's not too important. The second part is spot on and still wondering why the second directional derivative isn't that.

Comment: @runway44 I get that my assumption is incorrect for the second directional derivative, but intuitively for me it make sense and want to understand why it's wrong. Is there a visualization/intuitive proof of what the second directional derivative should be and what it represents?

Comment: I don't see anything intuitive about it other than notational similarity. For instance, one could argue $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$ is "intuitive" after seeing $2(a+b)=2a+2b$ and $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$. The meaning of the second directional derivative is that it is the second derivative of the function restricted to a line through the point in a certain direction (as in my other comment). Or since the first directional derivative is itself a scalar function you can think of it as the directional derivative applied twice in a row, $({\bf u}\cdot\nabla)^2f$, which is ${\bf u}\cdot\nabla({\bf u}\cdot\nabla f)$.

Comment: @runway44 ah I see. Thanks for the help, I'm understanding my mistake better now. Also off the top of your head do you know any applications of the second directional derivative? Is it similar to the second directional derivative in single variable calculus?